# condition in variable type list

Tags: ansible, yaml

I would like to add certain lines in a "list" type variable.
I do that

```
condition: 'true'

var_list:
  - template: "{{ playbook_dir }}/file1.j2", dest_dir: "{{ docker_volume_basedir }}/file1.txt"
  - template: "{{ playbook_dir }}/file2.j2", dest_dir: "{{ docker_volume_basedir }}/file2.txt"
  {% if condition == 'true' %}
  - template: "{{ playbook_dir }}/file3.j2", dest_dir: "{{ docker_volume_basedir }}/file3.txt"
  {% endif %}
```

but I have a nice style error ...

```
"message": "Syntax Error while loading YAML.\n  found character '%' that cannot start any token
```

have you an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using templated syntax in a vars file and that fails.

One of the ways i can think would be to do so at the runtime, for example

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    default_list:
      - template: "foo"
      - template: "bar"
    baz_list:
      - template: "baz"
    condition: false
  tasks:
    - name: append baz
      set_fact:
        default_list: "{{ default_list + baz_list }}"
      when: condition
```

Comment: perfect.
it works very well. (and it's very simple)

Thank you so much.